# Changing td background-color one per click

Tags: html

Here's the deal. I have this code. Quite simple, a table where the user
can click in any cell (except for the th's) an it will change it's color to green (done).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Coordenada</title>
  <style>
    table,
    th {
      width: 500px;
      text-align: center;
      border-color: #33CCFF;
    }
    .striped {
      background-color: #33CCFF;
    }
    .striped th {
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="font-family: Baskerville, 'Palatino Linotype', Palatino, 'Century Schoolbook L', 'Times New Roman', serif">
  <table border="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>H</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="striped">
      <th>1</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="striped">
      <th>3</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="striped">
      <th>5</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>6</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="striped">
      <th>7</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>8</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="striped">
      <th>9</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>10</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  <script>
    function mark(x) {
      x.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### What I really want is that only one cell remain green per click.

Example:

`Click on A1(Change to green)
Click on B1(Change to green, A1 return to it's default color)
Click on C1(Change to green, B1 return to it's default color)`

that way...

Answer (score 0):

Create a class(`green`) instead. When the `td` is being clicked loop through all `td`s, remove the class `green` if it exists and add the class to the `td` that was clicked.

```js
function mark(x) {
  var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    td[i].classList.remove('green');
  }
  x.classList.add('green')
}
```

```css
table,
th {
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  border-color: #33CCFF;
}
.striped {
  background-color: #33CCFF;
}
.striped th {
  color: white;
}
.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<body style="font-family: Baskerville, 'Palatino Linotype', Palatino, 'Century Schoolbook L', 'Times New Roman', serif">
  <table border="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>H</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="striped">
      <th>1</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="striped">
      <th>3</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="striped">
      <th>5</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>6</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="striped">
      <th>7</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>8</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="striped">
      <th>9</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>10</th>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
      <td onclick="mark(this)">XXX</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function mark(x){
 var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
 for(i=0; i < td.length; i++)
 {
  td[i].style.backgroundColor='';  // set all td bgclor defalut/remove color
 }

  x.style.backgroundColor='lightgreen';

    }
```

working demo http://jsfiddle.net/rgLeqgv4/